# Ajax XMLHttpRequest to MVC 5 HttpPost ActionResult without jquery

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, xmlhttprequest

Struggling to pass data object from `javascript` to `C# MVC 5`.
I don't want to use jquery.
I can return DataInterface to Javascript but cannot send it to the server.
Using Visual Studio DEBUG I get `DataInterface2.Age=0` and `DataInterface2.Name=null.`

Send from **Javascipt**: -

```
var uri = '/Action/ActionInterface'
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        fDone(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
    }
}
var data = { "Name": "Joe", "Age": 33  };
var sendstr = JSON.stringify(data);
xmlhttp.open("POST", uri, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xmlhttp.send(sendstr);
```

Receiving in **C#** :-

```
public class DataInterface
{
    public string Name;
    public Int16 Age;
    //public DateTime Birthdate;
}
public class ActionController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionInterface(DataInterface DataInterface2)
    {
        .... Using Debug DataInterface2.Age=0 and DataInterface2.Name=null 
        ....
        return Json(DataInterface1, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any console errors?

Comment: Not really -   
GET http://localhost:52062/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)  
This message graduates to -  
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:52062/favicon.ico   when I add the body html -  
<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
But this is before xmlhttp.send(sendstr);  
Nothing on xmlhttp.send(sendstr);

Comment: Make sure you have right array of `datainterface`

Comment: What array? "var data" isn't an array, "public class DataInterface" isn't.
I've just changed var data = { Name: "Joe", Age: 33  }; but no improvement.

Comment: I've also tried public ActionResult ActionInterface(string DataInterface2) since JSON.stringify changes data to a string and I get null.

Comment: try with parsing single node like `Name=Joe` in the url and then check at your backend like `ActionInterface(string Name)` and check are you getting a response or not

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM! It is the way I have declared DataInterface. I have missed out { get; set; }. It should be : -
  public class DataInterface
    {    
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Int16 Age { get; set; }
    }. Also extra "}" before var data = { "Name": "Joe", "Age": 33  };

Comment: cool yea great you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is use `public` variable, you need change to `property` with `getter/setter`.

Change from

```
public class DataInterface
{
    public string Name;
    public Int16 Age;
}
```

to

```
public class DataInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I tested in local machine, it worked.